# What do these errors mean and how do you suggest I fix them?

Tags: oracle

I am new to learning SQL and currently learning it in class. I am trying to write a code that fulfills the following requirements:

Make a reservation: Input parameters: Hotel, guest’s name, start date, end dates, room type, date of reservation. Output: reservation ID. NOTE: Only one guest per reservation. However, the same guest can make multiple reservations.

Find a reservation: Input is the guest’s name and date, hotel ID. The output is reservation ID

I am still somewhat new to deciphering error codes and tried to look up what they mean. However, I'm still not quite sure why my code is wrong.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE hotelmanagement AS

  FUNCTION make(rsrv_id    VARCHAR2
               ,hotel_name VARCHAR2
               ,guest      VARCHAR2
               ,start_date VARCHAR2
               ,end_date   VARCHAR2
               ,room_type  VARCHAR2
               ,rsrv_date  VARCHAR2)
  
   RETURN NUMBER IS
    rsrv_id NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT rsrv_seq.nextval INTO reserve_id FROM dual;
    INSERT INTO reservations
    VALUES
      (reserve_id, 'Four Seasons', 'Amanda', 'July-30-2019', 'Aug-8-2019',
       'King', 'July-18-2019');
    tot_rsrv := tot_rsrv + 1;
    RETURN(rsrv_id);
  END;

  FUNCTION find(guest     VARCHAR2
               ,rsrv_date VARCHAR2)
  
   RETURN NUMBER IS
    rsrv_id NUMBER;
  
  BEGIN
    SELECT rsrv_id
      INTO guest
      FROM reservations
     WHERE rsrv_date = find_rsrv_date;
  END;
  RETURN(rsrv_id);
END hotelmanagement;
```

I have these error messages(two of them look the same?):

> Error(4,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type      current cursor delete    exists prior The symbol "begin" was substituted for "SELECT" to continue.
>
> Error(5,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "RSRV_ID" when expecting one of the following:     language
>
> Error(5,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "RSRV_ID" when expecting one of the following:     language

Comment: Hmm, you're sure that MySQL tag is right? Looks more like Oracle...

Answer (score 3):

The requirements are a quite vague, so it is difficult to provide the desired procedure. Anyway, your code has some weak items.

- Your procedure has several input parameters but you don't use them inside the procedure.
- Use appropriate data types, i.e. **never(!)** store DATE or number values in string, i.e. `VARCHAR2`. Use `VARCHAR2` only for string data. At least you use four digit year, which is the proper way of doing it.
- `RETURN` command does not use brackets.

Taking all this into account your code should be more or less like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY hotelmanagement AS

  FUNCTION make( -- you can't declare variable "rsrv_id" twice 
               hotel_name IN VARCHAR2
               ,guest     IN VARCHAR2
               ,start_date IN DATE
               ,end_date   IN DATE
               ,room_type  IN VARCHAR2
               ,rsrv_date  IN DATE)    
   RETURN NUMBER IS

    rsrv_id NUMBER;

  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO reservations
    VALUES
      (rsrv_seq.nextval, hotel_name, guest, start_date, end_date,
       room_type, rsrv_date)
    RETURNING reserve_id INTO rsrv_id ;
    -- tot_rsrv := tot_rsrv + 1; -> I don't see any use for it, variable tot_rsrv is not declared
    RETURN rsrv_id;

  END;


  FUNCTION find(v_guest  IN VARCHAR2
               ,rsrv_date IN DATE) RETURN NUMBER IS

    rsrv_id NUMBER;

  BEGIN
    SELECT rsrv_id
    INTO rsrv_id
    FROM reservations
    WHERE rsrv_date = find_rsrv_date
        and guest = v_guest; -- don't use "guest = guest" because this will select all rows.

    RETURN rsrv_id;
  END;

END hotelmanagement;
```

Comment: That insert statement needs to specify the columns being inserted into.

Comment: @Boneist, columns for INSERT are not required - but for sure strongly recommended.

Comment: True, but in production code, they should always be specified. It's just good practice and will avoid bugs if someone adds a column and doesn't update the code.